# Want to use multiple &nbsp; in html?

Tags: html, format, whitespace

I have a situation where I want to space out the elements in html using more than one space. Is there any way other than using multiple `&nbsp;` ?

HTML:

```
<td width="10%">
    <a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></a>View&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i></a>Append&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>Delete
</td>
```

Comment: you can use `margin` OR `padding` if you want.

Comment: In that case I would have to create a new element between the two words. Isn't it?

Comment: You should provide additional information, such as the current HTML you have.

Comment: It might be better to modify your post and show us the HTML you're using and what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have added my html. I want to have more than one char space between the two anchor tags for a better spaced out view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out myself:
This can be achieved by the following depending on how much space you want:

```
&nbsp;    - single space
&thinsp;  - thin space
&ensp;    - en space(half the point size of the font)
&emsp;    - em space(point size of the font)
```

Reference: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/specialchars.html

This is what I have done:

```
<td width="10%">
    <a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></a>View&thinsp;
    <a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i></a>Append&thinsp;
    <a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>Delete
</td>
```

Hope this helps out.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS to change  the `margin` or `padding` to space out your elements is generally the accepted answer.

You could also go nuts and use `position: absolute` or `postion: relative` and space the elements out by playing with the `top` and `left` properties.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Just put it with following:-

```
<div class="space_lg">&nbsp;</div>
```

css

```
.space_lg
{
width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want consistently larger space, you can use `word-spacing`:

```css
p:first-of-type {
    word-spacing: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text that you want spaced</p>
<p>Some text with regular spacing</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `span` tag with `display:inline-block` and add `width` to it.

Answer (score -4):

There is no way to space. You should more   , I research it before, I didn't find any other way. Just, if you want to put space for all line, use br.

Comment: ı saw but he doesn't ask it.